# ObservableObject And Switching between views

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, observableobject, swiftui-environment

am a beginner in swiftui, still learning how to deal with ObservableObject
let me show my code and illustrate what is my question...

**JsonResponse as follows:**

```
{
  "error" : false,
  "user" : {
    "username" : "Maxwell",
    "id" : 84560,
    "name" : "Max",
    "authority" : "Manager"
  }
}
```

**Authenticate User Class (ObservableObject):**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct UserDetails{
    static var id: String = ""
    static var name: String = ""
    static var authority: String = ""
}

class AuthenticateUser: ObservableObject{
    @Published var isLoggedin: Bool = false
    
    func Authenticate(Username:String,Password:String){
        let url:String = "http://…./Login.php"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
        let data:  Parameters = ["username":Username,"password":Password]

        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate(statusCode: 200 ..< 299).response { AFdata in
            do {
                guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: AFdata.data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary else {
                    print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                    return
                }
                guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                    print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                    return
                }
                guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    print("Error: Cannot print JSON in String")
                    return
                }
                                    
                //if there is no error
                if(!(jsonObject.value(forKey: "error") as! Bool)){
                    print(prettyPrintedJson)
                    //getting the user from response
                    let user = jsonObject.value(forKey: "user") as! NSDictionary
                                        
                    //getting user values
                    let userID = user.value(forKey: "id") as! Int
                    let name = user.value(forKey: "name") as! String
                    let authority = user.value(forKey: "authority") as! String
                    //saving user values
                    UserDetails.id = String(userID)
                    UserDetails.name = name
                    UserDetails.authority = authority
                    self.isLoggedin = true
                }else{
                    //error message in case of wrong credentials
                    print("Wrong Credentials")
                    }
            
            } catch {
                print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login View:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Login: View {
        @StateObject private var loginManager = AuthenticateUser()
        @State var username = ""
        @State var password = ""
        var body: some View {
                ZStack{
                    
                        Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color(red: 33 / 255, green: 34 / 255, blue: 36 / 255))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                        VStack(){
                            Spacer()
                            Image("Logo")
                            Spacer()
                                VStack(){
                                    Text("RIVIERA BEACH CHALETS")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    Text("Administration System")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .fontWeight(.light)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            
                            Spacer()
                                Text("Sign in")
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            Spacer()
                            
                                VStack(){
                                    ZStack {
                                        if username.isEmpty {
                                            Text("Username")
                                            .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.3))
                                        }
                                        TextField("", text: $username)
                                            .padding()
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 1))
                                    }.padding(.horizontal,5).padding(.vertical,5)
                                    
                                    Spacer().frame(height: 15)
                                    
                                    ZStack {
                                        if password.isEmpty {
                                            Text("Password")
                                              .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.3))
                                        }
                                        SecureField("", text: $password)
                                            .padding()
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(Color.white,lineWidth: 1))
                                    }.padding(.horizontal,5).padding(.vertical,5)
                                    
                                    Spacer().frame(height: 15)
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Button(action:{
                                            //BUTTON ACTION
                                            loginManager.Authenticate(Username: username, Password: password)
                                            
                                        },label: {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text("AUTHENTICATE")
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                                .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.8))
                                            Spacer()
                                        })  .padding()
                                            .background(Color(red: 40 / 255, green: 41 / 255, blue: 43 / 255))
                                            .cornerRadius(20)
                                            
                                    }.padding(.horizontal,20).padding(.vertical,5).padding()
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                }.padding(20)
                        
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            
}

struct LoginPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Login()
    }
}
```

let me explain what is going on... and what is my question:
As you can see in code, we have a Json Object response being parsed as NS dictionary while revalidating the **UserDetails** variables with the data from the Json response, and a published Bool to detect whether logged in or not !
so the question is, how to setup that bool to let the view detect whether user logged in or not ... ? in another words ,what to type in the view code to let the app switch the view to Home view for example if logged in was true ... ? while parsing the user details to show it in that Home view.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You should look at [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink), specifically, one of the variants that takes a binding to `isActive`, such as [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(_:isactive:destination:)-gn8q). You can use your bool as this binding.

Comment: yeah, got it, actually good points to start with, but i cant figure it out on my own as a beginner, if u have any samples or so, would be helpful !

Comment: Here's an example of a NavigationLink using isActive: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/Swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui

Comment: Much better, it’s getting clearer more and more, thank you !